# error NG2012: Component imports must be standalone components, directives, pipes, or must be NgModules

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-services, syncfusion, angular-schematics

If we add some dependency in angular standalone component and app.module then show this error:

> error NG2012: Component imports must be standalone components, directives, pipes, or must be NgModules

[image]

[image]

Comment: please share minimal reproducible code, stackblitz if possible for debugging!

Comment: Are you add the line `import {TreeViewModule} from '@angular/material/tree';`in your standalone component? the message say you that you're trying import in a standalone component some that it's **not** a module, or another standalone component or directive or pipe, but it's possible that simply you forgot write the line before

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i am not forget to add any dependency it is syncfusion dependency: import { TreeViewModule } from '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-navigations'.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the shared details, we have confirmed successful import of the “**TreeViewModule**” from the “**@Syncfusion/ej2-angular-navigations**” package without encountering any reported issues.

We have attached a sample for your reference.

**Sample** : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1d5jjb-kfhrd6?file=src%2Fapp.component.ts

Additionally, we have provided the user guide documentation that explains the steps required to create a simple Angular TreeView component, and configure its available functionalities.

**Documentation** : https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/treeview/getting-started

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but i use angular 16 standalone component based & need to update same syncfusion library which are see in below.

   "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-buttons": "^18.2.54",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-charts": "18.2.56",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-dropdowns": "18.2.56",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids": "18.3.44",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-inputs": "18.2.56",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-layouts": "18.2.58",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-navigations": "18.2.55",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-popups": "18.2.58",

 please provide your suggestion it  run or not.